# print to a file shellscript

Tags: shell

I want to put this simple line to a file:
\"
The command I **must** use is: 
echo " any line " > file

But I can't find a way to use this simple command to put **\"**  to the file

If I do : echo " \" " > file or echo " \"" " > file. it returns error

If I do: echo " \" " > file. it returns: "

Comment: I must use : echo " " > file, not echo ' ' > file or any other way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backslash is an escape character, so you can use

```
echo "\\\"" > file
```

(N.B. the first blackslash escapes the second backslash and the third backslash escapes the quote)

Comment: @ngubk: Just put quotes around the term you want to output, it won't change it (as per my edit)...